# Why does NameOf(foo.First.Bar) works but NameOf(foo[0].Bar) doesn't?

Tags: c#, linq, nameof

When I try to run `NameOf(foo[0].Bar)` I get `"This sub-expression cannot be used inside NameOf argument"` error, which makes total sense to me.

But when I run `NameOf(foo.First.Bar)` it works and returns `"Bar"`.

While this seems intuitively ok, what's the proper explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Because `nameof` is evaluated at compile time, and `foo[0].Bar` is only available at runtime.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay wouldn't `foo.First` also be resolved at runtime?

Comment: No, `First` is the name of a property, and that is known at compile time.

Comment: The simple explanation is [that the spec says so](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11720-nameof-expressions). All it allows is simple member access. It would technically be possible to extend `nameof` to allow a smidge of evaluation logic (without actually evaluating), but this is likely more effort than warranted (it threatens the spectre of things like "do we need to apply overload resolution here to figure out the return type of this expression to see if the member exists", which seems very silly if the name is right there!)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Ohh, of course... as usual this seems obvious now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Correct, but `foo[0]` could never logically be allowed, because the item at index 0 doesn't make sense at compile time.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: So? We don't need to actually *access* `foo[0]`. Determining the (compile-time) type of the expression is certainly possible, and hence we can also resolve `.Bar`. There are pitfalls to allowing things like that, but "doesn't make sense at compile time" isn't one of them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, you are right, I see that now.

Comment: Since `nameof` works with types, and you should know the type of `foo[0]`, why not just replace it with its type: `nameof(fooType.Bar)`?

Comment: @NetMage I was changing some code to include undo/redo functionality and was initially using the same property been changed as argument for the `NaemOf`, but I actually ended up using it by Type as you suggested. My question was about the conceptual difference as I somehow missed that `.First` works as a property.